# how to get request id from create request document

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, java, partner-wsdl

Following is sample code that uses exacttarget partner API

```
    CreateOptions createOptions = CreateOptions.Factory.newInstance();
    // The six lines below are necessary if you want to do an update/add
    SaveOption sOption = SaveOption.Factory.newInstance();
    sOption.setSaveAction(SaveAction.UPDATE_ADD);
    sOption.setPropertyName("*");
    SaveOptions sa = SaveOptions.Factory.newInstance();
    sa.setSaveOptionArray(new SaveOption[] { sOption });
    createOptions.setSaveOptions(sa);

    CreateRequestDocument createRequestDocument = CreateRequestDocument.Factory.newInstance();
    CreateRequestDocument.CreateRequest createRequest = CreateRequestDocument.CreateRequest.Factory.newInstance();

    APIObject[] subArray = subscribers.toArray(new APIObject[0]);
    createRequest.setObjectsArray(subArray);
    createRequest.setOptions(createOptions);

    createRequestDocument.setCreateRequest(createRequest);

    CreateResponseDocument responseDoc = api.create(createRequestDocument);

    CreateResponse cr = responseDoc.getCreateResponse();
    CreateResult[] results = cr.getResultsArray();
```

How do I get request id in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Java.   But there should be something like

```
CreateResponse cr = responseDoc.getCreateResponse();
// cr.getRequestID();
// cr.getOverallStatus();
CreateResult[] results = cr.getResultsArray();
```

See [Create Method](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/methods/create/)